# Python Bubble Sort Looping Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, bubble-sort

So, I used to program in python a bit (in school) but I am recently getting back into it. I have two different for loops, one that I did myself (which doesn't work and is hashed out) and one that works (on the line above it).

I was wondering why the hashed out code doesn't work within the bubble sort function, it still loops the same number of times but for some reason when counting up the loop, the 99 will slowly move all the way to the end. However, when counting down, it completes this in 1 step. Here's the code

```
import random

unsorted_list = [2, 99, 95, 59, 54, 84, 6, 77, 45, 26]
print("The unsorted list is given as = ",unsorted_list)

def Bubble_sort(random_list):  
    Len_list = len(random_list)
    for pass_number in range(Len_list-1,0,-1):
    #for pass_number in range(0,Len_list,1):
        print(pass_number)
        print(random_list)
        for A in range(pass_number):
            if random_list[A] > random_list[A+1]:
                temp = random_list[A]    
                random_list[A] = random_list[A+1]
                random_list[A+1] = temp

Bubble_sort(unsorted_list)
```

Screenshots of my results running the two different loops separately can be seen below at links [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y61br.png) & [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko7SS.png). Link 1 is counting down (correct way) and link 2 shows counting up (incorrect results) but I don't know why they are incorrect.

My question is why doesn't it work both ways??

Thank you for helping!

Extra info = This was in python 3.9.0

Answer (score 1):

Only one of your outer loops overlaps properly with your inner loop.

That inner loop has one clear function: it walks the largest value down to position `pass_number`, one swap at a time.  Any other progress is a by-product; the critical outcome is that largest element.

When you start with `pass_number` at the end of the list (actually, one short: `A+1` is the end), the program works just fine: the first pass moves `99` to the end; the next moves 95 next to it, and so on.

It's important to note the opposite movement: a small value can only move to the left *one* position on each pass.

When you reverse only *one* loop, what you now have is a combination that will get *some* of the work correct, but is almost guaranteed to fail.  You don't touch the last element in the list until the final iteration; unless that last element happens to be one of the two largest, it *cannot* work its way to its proper position.  It is consulted only on the final iteration.

If you want to reverse the process, fine -- do so.  When you reverse the counting on pass_number, you also *must* reverse the restriction on the inner loop, so that the *first* iteration considers the entire list, in order.

Can you take it from there?  Figuring out that inner loop change is a good intro exercise.

Comment: Yeah I should be able to take it from here, thats very helpful, thank you.

Comment: Do remember to choose a "best answer", so SO can archive the question -- and I think you get a few points for it.